# Why is there no logical order in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have a problem with my SessionStorage. I stored all my items in a specific order, but when I try to get them back (with a `for` loop), they are not in the correct order.

Here is how I set my SessionStorage:

```
function set_Item(){
    var nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
    nom = nom.toUpperCase();
    sessionStorage.setItem("Nom", nom);
    sessionStorage.setItem("Prenom", document.getElementById("prnm").value);
    sessionStorage.setItem("Adr", document.getElementById("adr").value);
    sessionStorage.setItem("cdPost", document.getElementById("cdPost").value);
    sessionStorage.setItem("Ville", document.getElementById("ville").value);
    sessionStorage.setItem("Pays", document.getElementById("pays").value);
}
```

And this is how I get back my elements:

```
function get_Item(){
    var res = document.getElementById("res");
    var txt;
    var key;
    var valeur;
    for(var i = 0; i< sessionStorage.length; i++){
        key = sessionStorage.key(i);
        valeur = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        if(key == "Nom"){
            txt = document.createElement("p");
            txt.textContent = valeur + " " + sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(i+1));
            res.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',txt);
            i++;
        }else {
            txt = document.createElement("p");
            txt.textContent = valeur + " ";
            res.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',txt);
        }
    }
}
```

What I get:

[image: sessionStorage Items]

The order of the items is random and it sometimes changes.

I know that I can use the key to get the right items and set the good rendering order. But what's the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: It's an object which.. is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object or function.

Answer (score 2):

The order of keys in `Storage` object (i.e. both in session storage and local storage) is user-agent defined (i.e. the standard doesn't require any specific order and it's up to the user-agent/browser to decide on one).

From the [living HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface):

> The `key(n)` method must return the name of the *n*th key in the list. The order of keys is user-agent defined, but must be consistent within an object so long as the number of keys doesn't change. (Thus, adding or removing a key may change the order of the keys, but merely changing the value of an existing key must not.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over all `sessionStorage` items you can do

```
if(sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty("Nom")) {
    // your code here
} else {
    // your code here
}
```

and if the item is set to sessionStorage you can always access it like

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Nom", "Some Name I guess");
console.log(sessionStorage.Nom); // see this works
```

You also say:

> The order of the items is random and it sometimes changes.

follow this link, it might helps you understand the object order in javascript.
[Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)